# Why does flex-basis doesn't work with flex-direction: row?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I faced that issue when I tried to replace width by flex-basis. For example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent_1, .parent_2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.group_block_1, .group_block_2 {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.group_block_1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.group_block_2 {
  max-width: 100%;
  
}

.block_1, .block_2 {
  flex-basis: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.block_1:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}

.block_2:nth-child(3) {
  margin: 0;
}


/*for the first example*/
.parent_1 {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/*for the second example*/
.parent_2 {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.el {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_1">
  <div class="group_block_1">
    <div class="block_1">
      <div class="el"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block_1"></div>
    <div class="block_1"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="parent_2">
  <div class="group_block_2">
    <div class="block_2"></div>
    <div class="block_2"></div>
    <div class="block_2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`Flex-basis` works only in the first example when I established `flex-direction: column`. Why it doesn't work with `flex-direction: row`?

`.parent` is not flex container for `.block`, it's `.group_block`. So, why does the flex-direction of `.parent` impact on `.block`? I mean flex-direction is not inherited property.

P.S. And I know that flex-basis works like width for flex-direction: row and like height for flex-direction: column. But... `.group_container` is flex-container for `.block` and I didn't change the flex-direction for `.group_container`. It's always flex-direction: row.

***Updated***

The reason for this behaviour is `max-width: 100%`(that property was established in the second example). So, it's not about `flex-direction` at all. You can look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/52tf7x4z/), everything works. But I don't understand why flex-basis doesn't work with `max-width: 100%` or without any width for `.group_block` at all.

**ANSWER**

This question is closed and I don't want to ask a new one, so I write here...
The reason for this behaviour is that flex container (which is also flex item) doesn't consider the width (the width is established by flex-basis property) of its inner flex-item. That's why we should establish the width of our flex container (`width: 100%`), because by defaut it's auto (depends on inner content). This helps to expand the flex container to contain the flex-item inside.
I think this is happening only in those cases when flex container is also flex item, because [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wrjspnah/) everything works fine.

And it may also be interesting... The flex container ignores the width of its inner flex-item. That's why we can increase the width of flex-item by its content. [For example.](https://jsfiddle.net/7rtj5exg/)

Comment: you also need to reset flex-shrink to , else it shrinks to fit the width of the parent instead overflowing. flex-wrap:wrap can also needed if you do not want to use overflow.

Comment: in the duplicate read the section *flex-basis ignored in a nested flex container. width works.*